# How can I make a function that takes a function as an argument and returns a modified version of that function?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Basically I need to create a function in Haskell which takes a function as an argument and returns another function with all the same pattern matching but with one extra pattern to match against. I'm not sure how possible this is and I couldn't find anything on google, but that might be because the title is as concise as I could think how to phrase this problem!

For example, say I had a function defined like this:

```
example :: String -> Integer
example "a" = 1
example "b" = 2
example _   = 0
```

and then another function with type:

```
example2 :: String -> Integer -> (String -> Integer) -> (String -> Integer)
example2 str int f = ?
```

how could I write the second function so that it would return a function which did exactly the same as the first function, except also return the Integer `int` when passed the String `str`?

Comment: If you are nesting many of these "edits" upon each other, you should consider using a data structure to hold the mappings instead of a function. E.g. `Data.Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
example2 :: String -> Integer -> (String -> Integer) -> (String -> Integer)
example2 s x f = \a -> if a == s then x else f a
```

Note that this overrides any matching of `s` by `f`, i.e. `example2 "c" 3 example` is equivalent to:

```
f :: String -> Integer
f "c" = 3
f "a" = 1
f "b" = 2
f _   = 0
```